# Select for 2 things at once?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't know really how to explain this, but I basically want to check for 2 specific things in a table's properties.
The table is:

---

user:

```
name => "simples"
age => "Monday"
```

---

How would I check for both of those? I think it would look like:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM `data`.`user` 
          WHERE `user`.`name` = 'simples'
           AND `user`.`age`='monday';";
```

Comment: Means you want to check whether there is a row contains simples as name and age as monday?

Comment: @YashMehta Yes.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE name = 'simples' AND age = 'Monday';` seems like a basic select based on two columns in a table?

Comment: Please go to a tutorial site for a few days and go thru their tutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write Simple query:

**Basic syntax:**

```
select * from databasename.tablename where column_name1 = value1 and column_name2 = value2
```

**For Example:**

```
SELECT * FROM data.user WHERE name = 'simples' AND age = 'Monday'
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM user where name='simples' AND age='Monday'
```